# Apple script to lock computer using knock

Tags: applescript, screen-lock

There is a great app called [knock](http://www.knocktounlock.com) which lets you unlock your mac by tapping on your phone twice while in proximity.

http://www.knocktounlock.com

Unfortunately in order for the app on your phone to unlock your mac, you must have locked your computer using *their* lock utility.

The 3 ways I normally lock my computer do not seem to work with the app.
- [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com)
- control + shift + eject
- Waiting for screen saver

Their utility must be interfaced with a mouse and can not be triggered from the keyboard as far as I can tell.

How could you write a script (applescript?) that would lock the computer using their interface?

knock to unlock interface

[image]

[Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com) lock interface
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent a question to the support personel at knock, and they informed me that a script has already been written. The creator blogged about this just hours before this question was opened.

http://blog.ambroselittle.com/lock-mac-with-keyboard-shortcut-and-knock/

There is both an alfred workflow and an apple script to do this.